# Arduino UNO & Modem Sim800L - DNS Error when sending query params

Tags: http, arduino, sim900, sim800

I am using arduino UNO board, with modem sim800l. I want use it to send data to server, but the problem is that I receive 603 error when query parameters are supplied.

For

```
mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://subdomain.domain.ro&val=1\"");
```

The response is a 603 error.

For

```
mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://subdomain.domain.ro/&val=1\"");
```

The response is a 404 page.

It works fine for just:

```
mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://subdomain.domain.ro\"");
```

I validate all urls agains browser and they work just fine and the data is received.

The server is a NodeJS application behind a Nginx proxy set up only for http protocol with no redirect.

Comment: Have you tried to print the string you are sending? It seems like the `&` may be messing up your string to the SIM800L.

Comment: Have you tried escaping this & : `mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://subdomain.domain.ro\&val=1\""); ` ?

Comment: Yes I printed it and it's ok, I tried in browser too the printed string and it works. Yes I tried to escape it and is the same.

Comment: (Note that it not the same than in your second example)

Comment: mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=URL, subdomain.domain.ro/?val=1&val2=2");  You can also try sending like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

Need to escape both **?** and **&** and use **/**

```
mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://subdomain.domain.ro/\?val=1\&val2=2\"");
```

Comment: You mean \ ? As it seems to be the case?